# Does "x = x = .." (double equals/assignment) mean anything special?

Tags: java, syntax, variable-assignment

In a server programmed in Java, I found this statement:

```
buffer = buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
```

What I don't understand is that "buffer = " is stated twice.

Would not this code do the exact same thing?

```
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Sometimes you just want to make really sure the variable got assigned. ;-)

Comment: It means someone's really confused.

Comment: (You should consider that this might indicate a general carelessness in coding that could carry over elsewhere.)

Comment: Thanks, Hot Licks. It sure does!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java assignment (`=`) is evaluated right-to-left so,

- First `buffer` is assigned to `new byte[bufferSize]`
- then `buffer` is assigned to the value of `buffer`

While the second statement is exactly as you'd expect. `buffer` is assigned to `new byte[bufferSize]`.

It's likely the compiler would optimize this away.

Answer (score 1):

No difference between the two. It's a typo.